# Taking quotient of a variety by the additive group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology, torsors

**1.** Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible $\Bbb C$-variety,
on which the algebraic $\Bbb C$-group $G={\bf G}_{a,{\Bbb C}}$
(the additive group) acts freely on the right:
$$ X\times _{\Bbb C} G\to X,\quad (x,g)\mapsto x\cdot g.$$
Assume that there exists a surjective morphism
onto a smooth $\Bbb C$-variety $Y$
\begin{equation}\label{e:*}
\varphi\colon X\to Y \tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
whose fibres are the orbits of $G$ in $X$.
Then the morphism $\varphi$ is smooth, from which one can deduce that $\varphi$
induces a locally trivial fibre bundle (in the usual topology) of $C^\infty$-manifolds
$$\varphi\colon X(\Bbb C)\to Y(\Bbb C).$$

> **Question 1.** Does it follow that $(*)$
> is locally trivial in the *flat topology*, that is, a $Y$-*torsor* under $G$?
> In other words, is the morphism
> $$ X\times_Y G\to X\times_Y X,\quad (x,g)\mapsto (x,x\cdot g) $$
> an isomorphism of $\Bbb C$-varieties?

**2.** Assume that $(*)$ is a torsor.
Since $H^1({\Bbb C}(Y),G)=\{1\}$, we know that $(*)$ admits a rational section.

> **Question 2.** Does $(*)$ admit a *regular* section? In other words, does there exist
> a regular map (morphism) $s\colon Y\to X$ such that $\varphi\circ s={\rm id}_Y\,$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1, yes. In fact, any smooth morphism of varieties admits a section locally in the etale topology everywhere.

Proof: A generic hypersurface section is smooth of dimension one lower over any particular point. Repeat until the relative dimension is zero.

For 2, no. Any variety $Y$ with $H^1 (Y, \mathcal O_Y) \neq 0$ is a counterexample, as every class gives a torsor $X$.

Comment: Thank you, Will, for a prompt answer! Could you please add details to the proof for 1? A generic hypersurface section of what?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi of $X$. For example, take $y\in Y$, $x \in X$ with $\varphi(x)=y$, and choose any function on (a neighborhood of $x$ in) $X$ vanishing at $x$ and whose first derivative is nonzero on the relative tangent space of $X$ over $Y$. The vanishing locus of this function is still smooth over $Y$ at the point $x$, thus smooth over $Y$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Does it follow that a morphism $\varphi$ as in my question induces a locally trivial fibre bundle of complex analytic manifolds (with the usual topology)?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Yes. Locally trivializable in the etale topology implies locally trivializable in the flat, complex analytic, and several other topologies. In fact, the comparison between etale and Zariski cohomology for a quasicoherent sheaf implies that it is locally trivializable in the Zariski topology as well. The only subtlety I can think of, which applies equally to all these topologies, is that you want the *schematic* fibers to be orbits, i.e. you want the fibers to be reduced.

Comment: Thank you! Is your argument for "In fact, any smooth morphism of varieties admits a section locally in the etale topology everywhere" written somewhere, so that I could refer?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Probably, but I'm not sure where that exact statement appears. It follows quickly from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039P in the stacks project: Take a section of $\mathbb A^n_R$ over $R$ containing $\pi(x)$, and then pull back along $\pi$.